# Cloud function problem with promises, error when compiling

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, es6-promise, eslint

My cloud function is:

```
exports.onCommentarie = functions.firestore
.document('posts/{postId}/{commentaries}/{commentarieId}')
.onCreate((context) => {
  let postId = context.params.postId
  let commentarieId = context.params.commentarieId
  let commentarie = context.data.data().comment
  let ownerCommentarieName = context.data.data().creatorName
  let ownerCommentarieId = context.data.data().creatorId
  let postCreatorId = context.data.data().postCreatorId
  console.log(postCreatorId)
  const store = admin.firestore()
  store.collection('users').doc(postCreatorId).get()
  .then(doc => {
    let userToken = doc.data().tokenId
    return userToken
  })
  .then(userToken => {
    console.log(userToken)
    console.log('O token destino é:', userToken)
    console.log('O id de quem criou o post é:', postCreatorId)
    console.log('O comentário foi:', commentarie)
    console.log('O nome de quem comentou é:', ownerCommentarieName)
    console.log('o Id do post foi:', postId)
    console.log('o Id do comentário foi:', commentarieId)
    let message = {
      notification: {
        title: 'Comentário no seu post de:',
        body: ownerCommentarieName
      },
    token: userToken
  }
  admin.messaging().send(message)
  .then((response) => {
    return console.log('Successfully sent message:', response)
  })
  .catch(err => {
    return console.log(err)
  })
  })
})
```

It is resulting in a lot of junk errors, as follow:

```
  38:3  error    Expected catch() or return                  promise/catch-or-return
  43:9  error    Each then() should return a value or throw  promise/always-return
  58:3  warning  Avoid nesting promises                      promise/no-nesting
  58:3  warning  Avoid nesting promises                      promise/no-nesting
```

Why is lint saying that?

Comment: These are not "junk errors".  They are telling you things that make you code potentially incorrect (at worst) or difficult to read (at best).  I suggest searching each of these error messages to get some advice on how to improve your code.

Comment: Ok, i know that, that's why im asking how i should write my code with these errors, because a tried everything to fix the code and couldn't, it's a lint error (should be easy or few lines to fix).

Comment: It's not a few easy lines.  In your case, it's a significant restructuring of your function, given the volume of existing code and errors.